# Android ClassCastException:

Tags: java, android

I am trying to integrate a [Google Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) into an my own App. [The Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) illustrates the use of Camera2 API. The sample App compiles and runs just fine.

As said, I would like to use the `CameraActivity.java`, `Camera2BasicFragment.java` and `AutoFitTextureView.java` in my App. However, when I run my App, I get this error:

**java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.TextureView cannot be cast to openbook.pub.sypa.view.AutoFitTextureView**

The exception is thrown by this line (in `Camera2BasicFragment.onViewCreated`):

```
mTextureView = (AutoFitTextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
```

The `AutoFitTextureView` is unchanged from the sample app, and extends from TextureView:

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends android.view.TextureView {
```

I have even copied the `build.gradle` file from the Sample App to my own App., to make sure it depends on the same libraries. I have also cleaned the project.

Why do I get this error? And why does it work fine in Google's Sample App?

Comment: Obviously because view with id texture is not AutoFitTextureView but TextureView... It's like all dogs are animals but not all animals are dogs...  You cannot cast animal to a dog if it is not a dog

Comment: So my dog is barking up the wrong tree...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I get this error?

Presumably, the layout that inflated into `view` has a `TextureView`, not an `AutoFitTextureView`.

> And why does it work fine in Google's Sample App?

Because Google's sample app's [layout](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/res/layout/fragment_camera2_basic.xml) has an `AutoFitTextureView`.

Comment: You are right. I overlooked the TextureView in my layout file. That, however, was an attempt to work around a similar problem. I will ask another question for that issue.